# Bash script which works on both Windows and Mac

Tags: windows, bash, macos

Wirting a simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

wget -q https://get.helm.sh/helm-v${HELM_VERSION}-linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar -zxf helm-v${HELM_VERSION}-linux-amd64.tar.gz
mv ./linux-amd64/helm ${BIN_PATH}/helm
rm -rf linux-amd64/ helm-v${HELM_VERSION}-linux-amd64.tar.gz
chmod +x ${BIN_PATH}/helm
```

But I have to remove the end-of-line (CRLF & LF) every time I switch from Windows to Mac or vice-versa.

At the package doc2unix (https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/dos2unix) to handle these at the moment.

Is there any best practice how to handle this, so scripts can work seamlessly without any changes?

Comment: If you store your scripts in a git repository [and configure things appropriately](https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings), then (a) you get the benefits of version control for your project and (b) git will take care of end-of-line conversions for you.

Comment: @larsks This is what I was looking for, I am already using GIT (github.com) for version control but was not aware of this feature - thanks for sharing.

If you interested to answer it rather than comment, I will mark it as answered.

Comment: Or you can add a test using `uname -s`. e.g. `os=$(uname -s); if [[ $os == Linux ]]; then do_this; else do_that; fi` where `do_this` and `do_that` can be an action using `dos2unix`. The git solution is better imo.

Comment: @Jetchisel thank for sharing another approcah, yes conditionally can be handled as well though I agree handling in GIT is cleaner approach.

Comment: Use `bash -c "wget ...; tar ...; mv ...; rm ...; chmod ..."`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options,

1. If you are using a Git repository or a version control system, where a setting is available to automatically change line endings, from LF to CRLF. When a user downloads a script. Most users have a version control system, and prefer this method, if it is just line endings you are dealing with, when it comes to running the same script.
2. Have two versions of a file within two folders, which is one for Windows and one for Linux, or in your script write some code to detect what the OS is and then run your code which would work with the OS.
3. Software which can convert a file for executing from Windows to Linux, you are using one already called doc2unix